# What will happen if the "connectedness" is dropped/discarded from the domain of analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness, analytic-functions, analyticity

Let $G\subset\mathbb C$ be a non-empty open **connected** set and the function $f:G\to \mathbb C$ be analytic. It is easy to show that if there is a point $a\in G$ such that $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$, then $f\equiv 0$ on $G$. (I've used Taylor's series expansion of $f$ about the point $a$)

*My questions is:* If the ***"connectedness"*** of $G$ is dropped/discarded from the domain of $f$, what will happen? So, my specific question is sated as follows:

***Specific Question:*** Is there any ***non-zero*** analytic function on a non-empty open ***disconnected*** subset $G$ of $\mathbb C$ such that there is a point $a\in G$ such that $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Take **any** disconnected open set $G$ and write it as $G=U\cup V$ where $U,V$ are open, nonempty, disjoint sets. Now define $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ by $f(z)=0$ for $z\in U$ and $f(z)=1$ for $z\in V$.

Comment: If a function $f$ is analytic on $U$ as well as on $V$, then it is also analytic on $U\cup V$. Is it that?@Mark

Comment: An analytic function in an open set $G$ is a function which is differentiable in every point of $G$. So what you wrote is correct, it follows from the definition.

Comment: Further discussion: Does this $f$ have any analytic extension to the whole $\mathbb C$? If yes, I think the extension is not bounded by Liouville's theorem. Thus $f$ can have only a unique unbounded extension to $\mathbb C$. Is it not? Also,  any suggestions to  finding such extension of $f$ explicitely will be appriciated.

Comment: The function $f$ I defined can't be extended to an entire function. It has a point where $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$. So if it had an extension to all $\mathbb{C}$ then it would have to be the zero function (since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected), which contradicts the definition of $f$.